# How does owning aircraft / military vehicles work in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I'm hoping to buy an attack helicopter, but my garage doesn't have a helipad.  If I buy it, where does it spawn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you purchase a vehicle of this type, you pay some initial cost that varies.  Whenever you want to use said vehicle, you call Pegasus and they'll deliver it to you for GTA$200 (old gen) or for free (new gen).

Answer (score 1):

I think its much better to request Merryweather's helicopter pickup. It also costs $1k but it gets delivered to your current location. Simply throw the pilot out of the heli and enjoy your new toy.